# How do I get high-performance guitar microphone going for cheap?

Tags: audio, microphone

**Main question**:
Can I use a lot of cheap microphones off digikey and combine the signals somehow and will this make it sound like a higher-end mic?

How do you shop for a microphone: what specs are important in judging how "good" the mic will be?

Any experiences with microphones?  What did you find out regarding the above?  Thanks.

I will be sampling audio at 44 KHz approx and also transmitting it lossless.  This will probably be important in deciding whether or not I need a more expensive mic.

Comment: Found Optoacoustics company that makes fiber-optic mics.  How much do these cost, anyone?  Sent them an email....

Comment: "if your question … and it is not about a shopping or buying recommendation"  If you remove the "where can I buy" part and focus only on "Can I improve signal quality by using an array of low-cost microphones?" then it would be an allowed question.

Comment: Buy Rode or Sony microphones - they work great on my acoustic guitar and my voice even though it's me singing!! Don't mess around trying to re-invent the wheel just to save a few dollars. If you're serious about your music follow good advice. Sampling at 44kHz has no bearing on answers I believe. The internal electric components (such as JFET amplifier) of a microphone have very little bearing on the quality.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  @Andyaka so you suggest I provide a jack for a fancier mic that the user can buy?

Comment: @EnjoysMath I don't understand your question - what user? I use balanced XLR for my mic (not a jack aka 1/4" guitar thing) but XLR may be called a jack outside the UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key aspects of high-quality microphones include:

- **Frequency Response:** In many cases flatter is better, but many high-end microphones are selected for particular applications precisely because their responses are *not* flat. They might have just the right amount of high-end or low-end rolloff, or have a midrange boost in just the right place.
- **Pickup Pattern:** You have a choice of pickup patterns ranging from omnidirectional, to figure-8, to cardioids and super-cardioids. For the non-omnis, the off-axis frequency response can vary quite a bit from design to design. Again, this makes different microphones better for different situations.
- **Sensitivity and Dynamic Range:** It's difficult to produce a microphone that has good sensitivity for soft sounds while also having the robustness to handle loud ones. You'll use different models depending on the type of sound you're expecting.
- **Noise:** Especially if a microphone has an active preamp, the noise floor can become the limiting factor on the dynamic range.
- **Physical Robustness:** You wouldn't take your best studio microphone and give it to a singer to hand-hold in a live concert.

It would be difficult to achieve good scores in all of these areas with an array of cheap microphone cartidges, for a number of reasons.